# How to mount an NFS share on WSL2?

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, nfs, wsl2

How can I mount an NFS share from WSL2 on Windows 10?

```bsh
sudo mount -t nfs 192.168.1.101:/mnt/tank /mnt/tank
```

fails with

```bsh
mount.nfs: rpc.statd is not running but is required for remote locking.
mount.nfs: Either use '-o nolock' to keep locks local, or start statd.
```

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on windows-subsystem-for-linux.

Answer (score 4):

That error indicates that you're missing startup services, since WSL doesn't run systemd.

```
sudo /etc/init.d/rpcbind start
sudo /etc/init.d/nfs-common start
```

WSL2 changes ip addresses on each boot via the managed Hyper-V virtual switch, so you may need to ensure that the entire subnet is allowed on your server: `172.16.0.0/12`

Edit: As an alternative, try this: https://github.com/arkane-systems/genie

It sets up a "bottle" to run systemd as pid=1 and can start the systemd services needed for nfs mounts.

Comment: Did you have a chance to try this?  I did a quick test (I was going to edit your answer to add some info) and found that starting the rpcbind service errors out due to a missing `/run/sendsigs.omit.d` directory.  This is also a Systemd issue since (in a "normal" system) it is responsible for creating the necessary ephemeral `/run` directories for services.  I think you'll have to also create this manually each time (since it is tmpfs and disappears on restart).

Comment: I can rpcbind and portmapper this way, yes.

Comment: You might try this alternative, though: https://github.com/arkane-systems/genie

I haven't tried that yet, but basically it's a dotnet task that runs systemd and some other services for you.

Comment: ... I just installed genie and was able to nfs mount my NAS device (synology) doing little more than the indicated stems on the github page, so that seems to work. I'll edit / promote that a bit higher.

Comment: I wasn't really interested in doing this myself; just wanted to confirm that it worked as I was editing the answer and hit that issue.  Genie is a bit overkill to me, personally.  I can get Systemd up and running at a "good enough to test" level with a much more basic `unshare` and `nsenter` (which is what Genie ultimately does).  I wouldn't recommend it for this purpose, though.

Comment: In my distro I could run the initial commands, yes. But I hadn't set up my nfs server to see the subnet, so my mount failed at that point. I didn't see the error that you mention, so I probably can't help with that.

Comment: @Lar           Is it possible for you to edit with some instructions about how you got NFS to work after installing systemd-genie? I've been messing with it for a while and I'm still seeing the error `Failed to start rpc-statd.service: Connection reset by peer` when running mount.

Answer (score 3):

2023 update: [WSL2 now supports systemd](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/systemd-support-is-now-available-in-wsl/), even on Windows 10 if you install the Microsoft Store version of WSL2, and if you enable systemd in WSL2, it will start up any required daemons for you.